# Using a Javascript API in Ionic4

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to use an Javascript API (https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js) in a Ionic4 project. For that, I need to import the lib face-api.min.js into my folder. But as far i know, Ionic works just with Typescripts file ... I looked for docs but without success ...

Here is my code that I have working in Browser and I need to use in an Ionic project:

```
const video = document.getElementById('video')

Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
]).then(startVideo)

function startVideo() {
  navigator.getUserMedia(
    { video: {} },
    stream => video.srcObject = stream,
    err => console.error(err)
  )
}

video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video)
  document.body.append(canvas)
  const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height }
  faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize)
  setInterval(async () => {
    const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions()
    const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
    canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)
  }, 100)

})
```

The syntax it's the same of Typescript (except for document.GetElementById, but we will adapt), but will just works if I can call the API file.

Anyone knows how to implements an JS file in Ionic4 project?

Comment: Any valid line of JavaScript is a valid line of TypeScript. It's very common to use packages written in vanilla javascript in a typescript project.

Comment: But if i add any file of .js in my project he stops. Looks like only .ts extension are allowed.

Comment: Without seeing how you're doing this it's hard to determine what the issue is. But, there shouldn't be anything wrong with using a js file in your typescript project.

Answer (score 0):

There is library for loading asynchronous JavaScript files. https://www.npmjs.com/package/scriptjs

Install the package:

```
npm i scriptjs
```

Then use it anywhere like below:

```
import { get } from 'scriptjs';

ngOnInit() {

    get("assets/js/searchEmp.js", () => {
        getSerchInspContext = this;
        loadSearchEmp();
    });}
```

OR

You can simply use the jquery method to append or remove the script tag in your header.

To add .js file, call below on page load:

```
$('head').append('<script async src="assets/js/search.js"></script>');
```

Remove .js file:

```
document.querySelector('script[src="assets/js/search.js"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw an example github repository that you can check for references:

[Ionic4-ngx-face-api-js](https://github.com/ariffromeo/Ionic4-ngx-face-api-js)